# Accessing a variable (local or global) of PHP file from smarty

Tags: php, variables, smarty

I have a php file that has some local and global variables (e.g. $foo)
an smarty object is called from this file.
How can I access $foo from smarty script without changing PHP file?

Thanks

Comment: You need to assign the variable to the smarty object or smarty won't be able to access it. There's no magic wand to get around this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. You have to assign it to smarty within the PHP file.

```
$smarty->assign('foo', $foo);
```

Answer (score 11):

If you have a constant variable called BASE, and defined like this:

```
define('BASE', 'Boise');
```

you can access the variable in smarty the following way:

```
$smarty.const.BASE
```

Answer (score 7):

You used to be able to get around this by using `{php}{/php}` tags, but since this is deprecated, now you have to assign your variables via `$smarty->assign()`, the only exception to this is constants and server variables which you still have direct access to via the `$smarty` object.

(You can also re-enable the `{php}` tags if you'd like and don't care about the potential security reasons they were disabled for in the first place).

Any of the request variables such as `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_COOKIE`, `$_SERVER`, `$_ENV` and `$_SESSION` are available via the `$smarty` object.

Due to this - most of the data I work with can simply be accessed via the `$smarty` object without having to create a ton of (copied) variables.

eg.:

- Accessing a constant: `{$smarty.const.MY_CONST_VAL}`
- Accessing a $_SERVER var: `{$smarty.server.REQUEST_METHOD}` //[Everything in $_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) is accessible
- Grabbing something from $_SESSION: `{$smarty.session.MY_SESSION_VAL}` //[Everything in $_SESSION](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) is available