# Accessing $_SESSION['a']['b'] variable using smarty

Tags: php, session, smarty

I need to access value of $_SESSION['a']['b'] variable using smarty, 
In other words how can I rewrite this php code in smarty:

```
if ($_SESSION['a']['b']==1)
{
    do task #1
}
elseif ($_SESSION['a']['b']==2)
{
    do task #2
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking? Your code accesses the field, what's your actual problem? Please add what you've tried without success and what unexcpected error/results you get und what you actually expected. Please show your effort.

Answer (score 2):

See [Accessing a variable (local or global) of PHP file from smarty](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9035296):

> The request variables such as `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_COOKIE`, `$_SERVER`, `$_ENV` and `$_SESSION` are available via the `$smarty` object.

Grab something from `$_SESSION`:

```
{$smarty.session.MY_SESSION_VALUE} //Everything in $_SESSION is available.
```

Please check this above, you can directly call session in smarty.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my session variable is 2 dimensional !

Comment: @user3416269, First you can print session array then you can just access two dimensional array using dot operator. Hope this helps. If my answer helps then you can up-vote OR accept it. Let me know if you still have any issues.